# Only one default export allowed per module' but only one is presented

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a root 'App.js', and it only contains one 'export default'. It worked fine previously (It is mainly just a routing function for the application using React Navigation). But I need to see when tabs are focused so I attempted to implement this library: https://github.com/pmachowski/react-navigation-is-focused-hoc

Now when I load the application it gives me this error:

> 'Failed to load 192.168..... with error: ../../src/App.js: Only one
>   default export allowed per module'

But I believe I only have one; and this is App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator,createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { updateFocus, getCurrentRouteKey } from 'react-navigation-is-focused-hoc'

import SearchTab from './components/Tabs/SearchTab';
import HomeTab from './components/Tabs/HomeTab';
import ScannerTab from './components/Tabs/ScannerTab';
import SettingsTab from './components/Tabs/SettingsTab';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import StockModal from './components/Modals/StockModal';

const MainStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Home: HomeTab,
        Search: SearchTab,
        Scanner: ScannerTab,
        Settings: SettingsTab,
        //Todo: Total overlay modals HERE
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
                const { routeName } = navigation.state;
                let iconName;

                if (routeName === 'Home') {
                    iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
                } else if (routeName === 'Settings') {
                    iconName = `ios-options${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
                }else if (routeName === 'Scanner') {
                    iconName = `ios-barcode${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
                }else if (routeName === 'Search') {
                    iconName = `ios-search${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
                }
                return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
            },
        }),
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: 'tomato',
            inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        },
    }
);


DefaultStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Main: {
            screen: MainStack,
        },
        QuickStockScreen: {
            screen: StockModal,
        },
    },
    {
        mode: 'modal',
        headerMode: 'none',
    }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <DefaultStack
                onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState) => {
                    // If you want to ignore the state changed from `DrawerNavigator`, use this:
                    /*
                      if (/^Drawer(Open|Close|Toggle)$/.test(getCurrentRouteKey(currentState)) === false) {
                        updateFocus(currentState)
                        return
                      }
                    */
                    updateFocus(currentState)
                }}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Also; another way for me to solve this issue would be another more 'up to date' library or method of receiving a prop or state when a tab within React Navigation is focused; From even [their own issue thread](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/51) the method is messy and unclear.

```
Failed to load bundle(http://192.168.0.10:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(SyntaxError: /Users/kenji/StockManager/src/App.js: Only one default export allowed per module. (73:0)

[0m [90m 71 | [39m}[0m
[0m [90m 72 | [39m[0m
[0m[31m[1m>[22m[39m[90m 73 | [39m[36mexport[39m [36mdefault[39m [33mRootStack[39m [33m=[39m createStackNavigator([0m
[0m [90m    | [39m[31m[1m^[22m[39m[0m
[0m [90m 74 | [39m    {[0m
[0m [90m 75 | [39m        [33mMain[39m[33m:[39m {[0m
[0m [90m 76 | [39m            screen[33m:[39m [33mMainStack[39m[33m,[39m[0m (null))

__38-[RCTCxxBridge loadSource:onProgress:]_block_invoke.248
    RCTCxxBridge.mm:422
___ZL36attemptAsynchronousLoadOfBundleAtURLP5NSURLU13block_pointerFvP18RCTLoadingProgressEU13block_pointerFvP7NSErrorP9RCTSourceE_block_invoke.118
__80-[RCTMultipartDataTask URLSession:streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:]_block_invoke
-[RCTMultipartStreamReader emitChunk:headers:callback:done:]
-[RCTMultipartStreamReader readAllPartsWithCompletionCallback:progressCallback:]
-[RCTMultipartDataTask URLSession:streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:]
<redacted>
<redacted>
<redacted>
<redacted>
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_block_invoke_direct
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_block_invoke_direct
dispatch_block_perform
<redacted>
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_continuation_pop
_dispatch_async_redirect_invoke
_dispatch_root_queue_drain
_dispatch_worker_thread3
_pthread_wqthread
start_wqthread
```

Comment: have you saved the App.js file to disk ?

Comment: Indeed, I even cleaned the build folder entirely for xcode

Comment: can u share full stack of error ?

Comment: Added in; I had to copy the error from my phone and add it in through the stackoverflow app as it doesnt even print in the React Native Debugger (infact nothing but 'console cleared' prints currently)

Answer (score 0):

So I suspect it was a bizzare issue of file permissions or something similar.
I am running hackintosh to develop iOS with xcode and real-device testing and  booting can be odd; for instance loading what was put 'on hold' when shutting down sometimes wont act correctly.

This was the case, after a proper dead restart it fixed.
I realized this was an issue after I reverted the changes to App.js and the exact same issue was still showing.